# how to add a new row button for the jqgrid inline navigator whitout showing the modal dialog form?

Tags: button, jqgrid, addition, jqgrid-inlinenav

I am using the example in the [jqGrid Demos page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) located in **Row Editing** > **Inline Navigator**, but I need to have my add button out of the navigator like in example **Live Data Manipulation** > **Add Row**. I have already placed the add button:

```
<table id="editgrid" ></table> <div id="pagered" ></div> <input type="BUTTON" id="bedata" value="Edit Selected" />
```

and the event

```
$("#bedata").click(function(){ jQuery("#editgrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',"new",{height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}); });
```

My question is, what is the name of the event or the configuration of the jqgrid that I have to use, in order to insert the new row directly in the grid like in the inline navigator example whitout the modal form dialog when I click the **betadata** button?

I have already set the **modal** property to false, but it doesn't work,

Any help would be really appreciated

**ANSWER:**

The name of the event is **addRow**, I found it in [the inline-editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) document.